# Cannot convert value of type 'AES' to expected argument type 'UnsafeRawPointer?'

Tags: ios, swift, type-conversion, unsafe, unsafemutablepointer

I have some problem with this code:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation
import CryptoSwift
class StartViewController: UIViewController {
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
let key = "bbC2H19lkVbQDfakxcrtCCQdd0FloLyw" 
        let iv = "gqLOHUioQ0QjhusP" 
        let s = "my test string"
do {
            let data = s.data(using: .utf8)
            let enc = try AES(key:key,iv:iv,blockMode:.CBC,padding:PKCS7())
            let encData = NSData(bytes:enc,length:Int(enc.count))

        } catch {
            print("error")
        }
}
```

And now show me this error:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'AES' to expected argument type 'UnsafeRawPointer?'
```